# Communication between controllers JavaFX

Tags: javafx, controller, communication, scene

I´m trying to display an image on a new windows when I click on a rectangle of my main stage but I receive the following error: "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException"

First controller (ControllerImpl) initializes second controller (ControllerImage) and calls one of its methods (controllerImage.displayImageSel):

```
    @FXML
private ControllerImage controllerImage = new ControllerImage();
public void rectangleSave(Rectangle r, String imagePath) {
    r.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
        try {
            Stage imageStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/images.fxml"));

            Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
            imageStage.setX(0);
            imageStage.setY(0);
            imageStage.setHeight(primScreenBounds.getHeight());
            imageStage.setWidth(primScreenBounds.getWidth() * 0.7);
            imageStage.setTitle("JavaFX Scene Graph Demo");

            Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
            imageStage.setScene(scene);
            imageStage.show();

            controllerImage.displayImageSel(imagePath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Me cago en el PP");
        }
    });
}
```

Second controller contains a stack pane and method called by ControllerImpl:

```
@FXML
public StackPane Spi;
public void displayImageSel(String imagePath) {
    Rectangle ri = new Rectangle();
    Spi.getChildren().add(ri);
    Image image = new Image(new File(imagePath).toURI().toString());
    ri.setFill(new ImagePattern(image));
}
```

Of course Spi is defined in FXML file:

```
       <StackPane fx:id="Spi"......
```

Problem is ControllerImage can't find StackPane Spi. I´ve been implementing all kind of solutions I found related to this but no one has worked so far.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: new error message

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
```

/C:/tutorial-app/tutorial-app/target/resources/main/images.fxml
/C:/tutorial-app/tutorial-app/target/resources/main/images.fxml

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2755)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2704)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at tutorial.controller.impl.ControllerImpl.lambda$rectangleSave$1(ControllerImpl.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `controllerImage` yourself, not through `FXMLLoader`, so the FXML fields never get injected. <s>You also never call `load` on that loader.</s>   **Edit:** Oops, you do, I just missed it.

Assuming you have the `fx:controller` set correctly in "images.fxml", remove the assignment of `controllerImage` and add this line after the call to `FXMLLoader#load`:

```
controllerImage = loader.getController();
```

If you don't have `fx:controller` set in the FXML you can either set it to the correct class, or instead pass the instance you create to the loader **before** loading:

```
loader.setController(controllerImage);
```

In this case you would of course keep the initialization of `controllerImage`.

Comment: Cheers mate, I´ve applied your changes and now it catches IOException and prints "Me cago en el PP". Do you have any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Try adding `e.printStackTrace()` to the `catch` clause and post the complete stack trace. Just `IOException` is too broad, but a likely cause it wrong image path, or insufficient permissions to open the requested file.